# How to fetch a credential securely from a server in android app?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I am trying to use the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API library in my Android app. There is an example of client code from Google on Kotlin [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/SpeechRecognitionClient).

It has a code snippet:

```
        // NOTE: The line below uses an embedded credential (res / raw / sa.json).
        // You should not package a credential with real application.
        // Instead, you should get a credential securely from a server.
        context? .resources? .openRawResource (R.raw.credential).use {
            SpeechClient.create (
                SpeechSettings.newBuilder ()
                    .setCredentialsProvider {GoogleCredentials.fromStream (it)}
                    .build ())
        }
```

My app has a backend server.
How actualy to "get a credential securely from a server"? Is there any examples?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech)

> Set Up to Authenticate With Your Project's Credentials
>   This Android app uses JSON credential file locally stored in the resources. You should not do this in your production app. Instead, you should **set up your own backend server that authenticates app users. The server should delegate API calls from your client app**. This way, you can enforce usage quota per user. Alternatively, you should get the access token on the server side, and supply client app with it. The access token will expire in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) provided by John should give you some insights as it examines how to identify using OAuth for a Web Server application.

More in line with your actual case you can look at [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app), more precisely at [AppAuth](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/) for Android library. You can follow this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#0) as suggested in the official documentation.

Edit: If the above is not useful then, I assume you are more interested in [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

If the clients will be using your credentials then I would modify the code so that all the API calls are made from the backend server and the client side sends the necessary information to the server to make the call. Then, for authentication I would use a service account following [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Pay attention to the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#best_practices_for_managing_credentials) described at the end of the document.

Comment: I read the information on the links. So far, I only realized that with the help of Oauth2 it gives the opportunity to access the user's personal data. However, I do not need user data, I need to make a request to the API for speech recognition, it does not concern user data and it uses the token that I generated in the Google developer console.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you were actually looking for. I have edited my answer with some new information that might be more useful to your case. Let me know if it helps or not.